# Change class of div depending on display size

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

So I'm using the Skeleton Framework (getskeleton.com) to make web development and design easier. It uses classes in order to change how much space an element is going to use in the grid. For example, to use half of the space you would set the class of the div to be "six columns" (out of a total of twelve).

Now, what I would like to do is change the class of an element when the screen size is less than a specific amount. This way, when the screen is less than X px I could change the class of a div element to make it full width.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As the skeleton classes have predefined values and you should not modify their properties, the solution is using jquery to add or remove class names:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   var width = $(window).width();
   //Assuming X=550   
   if(width <= 550){
       $('#element').removeClass('one-half').addClass('one');
   }
   else{
       $('#myelement').removeClass('one').addClass('one-half');
   }
})
```

also trigger a resize() on documnt.ready to initialize width check:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
.resize()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead to change the class, you can use the `CSS media query` to let the class react in different ways based on the screen size

This tecnique is called "Responsive" and is used for example to make a web site fit properly in a smartphone

Example

```
<style>
.myclass{width:1000px} /* applied in all resolution > 320px */

@media (max-width: 320px) {
.myclass{width:100px}  /* applied in resolution < = 320px (smartphone) */
}
</style>
```

> You can create many media query for many resolution to adapt your
>   solution in all desktop, tablet and smartphone

Hope it help

Comment: **Skeleton** has predefined classes and you cannot modify class definitions.

Comment: You dont have to modify any class but add a new part of CSS to handle those classes in a different resolution by css media query

Comment: in Skeleton every class is predefined and adding or removing any css property will stop skeleton from working. Adding and removing predefined classes to/from elements through javascript is the only solution to challenge with Skeleton.